# Is there a way to resolved CocoaPod dependency issue? (WebexSDK + Socket.IO)

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a project that uses both WebexSDK and SocketIO, when i'm trying to add both via Cocoapods i'm getting the following error:

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Starscream":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Starscream (= 4.0.0)

In Podfile:
    Socket.IO-Client-Swift (~> 15.2.0) was resolved to 15.2.0, which depends on
      Starscream (~> 3.1)

```
WebexSDK (~> 2.5.0) was resolved to 2.5.0, which depends on
  Starscream (= 4.0.0)
```

Specs satisfying the `Starscream (= 4.0.0), Starscream (= 4.0.0), Starscream (~> 3.1)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

My pod file:
pod 'WebexSDK', '~> 2.5.0'
pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 15.2.0'

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods can't resolve this conflict. If you absolutely need both of these libraries, you will need to change at least one of them to regain compatibility (or wait for the respective authors to do so).